# Merging JSON files using jenkins groovy

Tags: json, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have multiple JSON files with the following structures

FILE1.json

```
{
    "Plugins": [
        {
            "Name": "Async Http Client",
            "Installation": [
                {
                    "Version": "1.7.24.2",
                    "Enabled": true,
                    "URL": "http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Async+Http+Client+Plugin",
                    "Server": "Server1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "Common API for Blue Ocean",
            "Installation": [
                {
                    "Version": "1.10.2",
                    "Enabled": true,
                    "URL": "https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Blue+Ocean+Plugin",
                    "Server": "Server1"
                }
            ]
        },
.
.
.
    ]
}
```

FILE2.json

```
{
    "Plugins": [
        {
            "Name": "Async Http Client",
            "Installation": [
                {
                    "Version": "1.7.24.1",
                    "Enabled": true,
                    "URL": "http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Async+Http+Client+Plugin",
                    "Server": "Server2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "Common API for Blue Ocean",
            "Installation": [
                {
                    "Version": "1.10.2",
                    "Enabled": true,
                    "URL": "https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Blue+Ocean+Plugin",
                    "Server": "Server2"
                }
            ]
        },
.
.
.
    ]
}
```

FILE3.json

```
{
    "Plugins": [
             {
            "Name": "Common API for Blue Ocean",
            "Installation": [
                {
                    "Version": "1.10.1",
                    "Enabled": true,
                    "URL": "https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Blue+Ocean+Plugin",
                    "Server": "Server3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "Support Core Plugin",
            "Installation": [
                {
                    "Version": "2.54",
                    "Enabled": true,
                    "URL": "https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Support+Core+Plugin",
                    "Server": "Server3"
                }
            ]
        },
.
.
.
     ]
}
```

I want to merge them into a **single file** with the following structure using **groovy**

MergedFile.json

```
{
    "Plugins": [
        {
            "Name": "Async Http Client",
            "Installation": [
                {
                    "Version": "1.7.24.2",
                    "Enabled": true,
                    "URL": "http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Async+Http+Client+Plugin",
                    "Server": "Server1"
                },
                {
                    "Version": "1.7.24.1",
                    "Enabled": true,
                    "URL": "http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Async+Http+Client+Plugin",
                    "Server": "Server2"
                }

            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "Common API for Blue Ocean",
            "Installation": [
                {
                    "Version": "1.10.2",
                    "Enabled": true,
                    "URL": "https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Blue+Ocean+Plugin",
                    "Server": "Server1"
                },
                {
                    "Version": "1.10.2",
                    "Enabled": true,
                    "URL": "https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Blue+Ocean+Plugin",
                    "Server": "Server2"
                },
                {
                    "Version": "1.10.1",
                    "Enabled": true,
                    "URL": "https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Blue+Ocean+Plugin",
                    "Server": "Server3"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Name": "Support Core Plugin",
            "Installation": [
                {
                    "Version": "2.54",
                    "Enabled": true,
                    "URL": "https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Support+Core+Plugin",
                    "Server": "Server3"
                }
            ]
        },
      .
      .
      .
      ]
}
```

I am looking for a jenkins pipeline script using jenkins groovy. The file structure of the 3 files are the same. Only the file content maybe different. If there is any common "Name", "Installation" is merged under the same "Name" like mentioned above.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit:
I've tried something like this..

```
        files = findFiles(glob: "*.json")
        def input
        def mergedjson = readJSON file:"${files[0]}"
        for (f=1;f<files.size();f++)
        {
            input=readJSON file:"${files[f]}"
            i = input.Plugins.size()
            j = mergedjson.Plugins.size()

            for (x=0;x<i;x++)
            {
                def json_status=0   
                for (y=0;y<j;y++)
                {
                    if (input.Plugins[x].Name == mergedjson.Plugins[y].Name)
                    {
                        mergedjson.Plugins[y].Installation += input.Plugins[x].Installation
                        json_status=1
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (json_status == 0)
                    mergedjson.Plugins[j++] = input.Plugins[x]
            }
        }


inventory=JsonOutput.prettyPrint(JsonOutput.toJson(mergedjson))
writeFile([file: "Inventory.json", text: inventory])
```

I am getting the following error
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException.(InvocationTargetException.java:72)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor544.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaBeanProperty.getProperty(MetaBeanProperty.java:59)
    at groovy.lang.PropertyValue.getValue(PropertyValue.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.getProperties(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:389)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.getObjectProperties(JsonOutput.java:327)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:320)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeMap(JsonOutput.java:458)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:321)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeMap(JsonOutput.java:458)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:321)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeMap(JsonOutput.java:458)
    at groovy.json.JsonOutput.writeObject(JsonOutput.java:321)
    .
    .
    .

Comment: What have you tried?  Please add your attempts and how they failed so we can improve from there.

Comment: @cfrick, I've added my approach. I'm pretty sure the answer will involve something with using collect method and other groovy json methods, but i do not understand it enough to tackle it.